# In KSP-Interstellar, is there a way to disable a fission reactor?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I've installed KSP-Interstellar and I'm enthusiastic of this beautiful mod, but I'm still far from understanding all of its complex mechanics. One of the problems I'm facing now is the excess of WasteHeat. As you can see in the screenshot I've covered my (oversized) space station with Huge Radiators but it still can't completely dissipate all the heat produced by the four "Aegletes 2" fission reactors. As far I can read on [this page](https://github.com/FractalUK/KSPInterstellar/wiki/Waste-Heat-Management) I'm quite low on radiators. I have 20 and that should be enough for just one "Aegletes 2" fission reactor. So, periodically, my reactors overheat and when are at 95% of the total WasteHeat capacity, they shutdown and I have to do EVA to restart them. Surprisingly enough, this happens even with just one reactor active, so I'm stuck in this endless loop. So the question is: given that there is no "shutdown" button, is there an unofficial way to shutdown fission reactors without doing EVA? And as side-question, how can I upgrade my radiators to disperse more heat?

Thank you for any help

[image: KSP-Interstellar space station]

Comment: One thing you can do is fold away all your solar panels.  They really aren't needed.  Your generators will also produce electric charge, and extended solar panels also build up waste heat.

Comment: Ok, I unfolded them just because my reactors were shut down and electriccharge went down pretty quickly. Meanwhile I thought that maybe I could somehow cut the fuel to the reactors, don't know how, but this should work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the options on a parts context sensitive menus are defined in the mod files. As "shutdown/restart/toggle reactor" are set to EVA only on the fission reactors, you would have to modify these mod files. However this is all compiled into `\GameData\WarpPlugin\Plugins\WarpPlugin.dll`

Also, there is no defined upgrade for radiators, however you can modify the max temp of the radiators in `WarpPlugin\Parts\Electrical\LargeFlatRadiator\radiator.cfg` or `\GameData\WarpPlugin\Parts\Electrical\HeatRadiator\radiator.cfg` (there are others in the Electrical directory).

InterstellarMod Models heat dispersion based on area and max temp (Read more detail [here](https://github.com/FractalUK/KSPInterstellar/wiki/Radiators)) So altering these settings will have an effect (use at your own risk).